# HP Proliant ml350 Gen9 don't start

Tags: hardware

I have an **HP Proliant ML350 Gen9 server** but it won't boot. It has two power supplies, its pilots turn green as soon as I plug in the power cable. The mother board pilot also turns green. On the front of the server, the power lights up orange. When pressing power, nothing happens.

No pilot blinks, all are permanently lit!

I've tried to completely clean the machine, even it didn't react, I tried to do a test using only one power supply at a time to see if the problem could be in one of the sources, it still doesn't react.

What can it be and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you plugged in all it power modules and power sources to them?

Comment: Yes, but I realized that there is a problem in the board that joins the power supplies together to feed the motherboard. I sent a similar sign to replace it. Thanks